# could not find file existing file while converting from .tex to pdf in python

Tags: python, math, latex, pdf-generation, pdflatex

I need to convert latex file to pdf. I try to do it like in documentation written:

```
import subprocess, os
from tex import latex2pdf,tex2pdf
from latex import build_pdf
from pdflatex import PDFLaTeX


with open('sometexfile.tex','w') as file:
    file.write('\\documentclass{article}\n')
    file.write('\\begin{document}\n')
    file.write('Hello Palo Alto!\n')
    file.write('\\end{document}\n')


with open('sometexfile.tex', 'rb') as f:
    file_to_read = f.read()
    pdfl = PDFLaTeX.from_binarystring(file_to_read , 'sometexfile')

pdf  = pdfl.create_pdf()
```

And I got an error:

> line 20, in 
> pdf  = pdfl.create_pdf()  The system cannot find the file specified

How should I solve my problem?

Comment: Could you please specify your `import`s?

Comment: It is done now.

Comment: Sry, I cannot reprocude the error. If I execute your code, it just works. Are you sure that this is your whole code? Did you actually try to execute that code you posted?

Comment: Of course. I made this code twice. In Pycharm and in Idle Shell

Comment: I use it in windows

Comment: Sry, I have no Windows around here, so I cannot test under Windows.